# MYSQL How to count elements grouped by type

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a problem with a query:
I have a list of stores, each of these stores has members and there are various categories of membership (Bronze, silver, gold ...)

The tables are: 'shops', 'members', 'membership_cards'.

```
shops: id, name
members: id, shops_id, membership_id, first_name, last_name
membership_cards: id, description
```

I need to extract the count of members, grouped by membership of each stores. Can I do this without using a server side language?

The final result should be something like:

Store's name, n°bronze members, n°silver_members, n°gold_members ....

Comment: This can certainly be done with a SQL query, but you need to give us more details on the table schemas so we can understand the relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you provided, you want a query like:

```
select shopid,
       sum(case when c.cardtype = 'Bronze' then 1 else 0 end) as Bronze,
       sum(case when c.cardtype = 'Silver' then 1 else 0 end) as Silver,
       sum(case when c.cardtype = 'Gold' then 1 else 0 end) as Gold
from shops s left outer join
     members m
     on s.shopid = m.shopid left outer join
     cards c
     on c.memberid = m.memberid
group by shopid
```

If you want to know the number of members, rather than of cards in each group (if members can have more than one card), then replace the sum() expression with:

```
count(case when c.cardtype = 'Bronze' then m.memberid end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your database schema, it's a bit hard to answer that question, but something like the following should do the job:

```
SELECT      shop.name,
            SUM(CASE WHEN membership_cards.category = 'Bronze' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Bronze,
            SUM(CASE WHEN membership_cards.category = 'Silver'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Silver,
            SUM(CASE WHEN membership_cards.category = 'Gold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold
FROM        shops
INNER JOIN  members
ON          shop.id = members.shopid
INNER JOIN  membership_cards 
ON          members.id = membership_cards.memberid
GROUP BY    shop.name
```

Just change the column names to the names you are using.

Comment: ok this one is good for me, it's possible to show all the stores? even the ones that don't have any members?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.name,A.Bronze,A.Silver,A.Gold    
FROM
(
    SELECT S.id,
        SUM(IF(IFNULL(C.cardtype,'')='Bronze',1,0)) Bronze,
        SUM(IF(IFNULL(C.cardtype,'')='Silver',1,0)) Silver,
        SUM(IF(IFNULL(C.cardtype,'')='Gold'  ,1,0)) Gold
    FROM shops S
    LEFT JOIN members M ON S.id = M.shops_id
    LEFT JOIN membership_cards C ON M.membership_id = C.id
    GROUP BY S.id
) A
INNER JOIN shops B USING (id);
```

I used the [**IFNULL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function in case any member has no cards